# Downsides of structuring all multi-threading CSP-like

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Disclaimer: I don't know much about the theoretical background of [CSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes).

Since I read about it, I tend to structure most of my multi-threading "CSP-like", meaning I have threads waiting for jobs on a `BlockingQueue`.
This works very well and simplified my thinking about threading a lot.

- What are the downsides of this approach?
- Can you think of situations where I'm performance-wise better off with a `synchronized` block?
- ...or Atomics?
- If I have many threads mostly sleeping/waiting, is there some kind of performance impact, except the memory they use? For example during scheduling?

Comment: There's always a tradeoff when using higher abstractions. Whether it matters is a different thing. It's better to have a working, understandable architecture than a slightly faster mess. And as always with performance questions: profile, profile, profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possibly way to designing the architecture of your code to prevent thread issues from even happening, this is however not the only one and sometimes not the best one.

First of all you obviously need to have a series of tasks that can be splitted and put into such a queue, which is not always the case if you for example have to calculate the result of a single yet very straining formula, which just cannot be taken apart to utilize multi-threading.

Then there is the issue if the task at hand is so tiny, that creating the task and adding it into the list is already more expensive than the task itself. Example: You need to set a boolean flag on many objects to true. Splittable, but the operation itself is not complex enough to justify a new Runnable for each boolean.

You can of course come up with solutions to work around this sometimes, for example the second example could be made reasonable for your approach by having each thread set 100 flags per execution, but then this is only a workaround.

You should imagine those ideas for threading as what they are: tools to help you solve your problem. So the concurrent framework and patters using those are all together nothing but a big toolbox, but each time you have a task at hand, you need to select one tool out of that box, because in the end putting in a screw with a hammer is possible, but probably not the best solution.

My recommendation to get more familiar with the tools is, that each time you have a problem that involves threading: go through the tools, select the one you think fits best, then experiment with it until you are satisfied that this specific tool fits the specific task best. Prototyping is - after all - another tool in the box. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> What are the downsides of this approach?

Not many.  A queue may require more overhead than an uncontended lock - a lock of some sort is required internally by the queue classs to protect it from multiple access.  Compared with the advantages of thread-pooling and queued comms in general, some extra overhead does not bother me much.

> better off with a synchronized block?

Well, if you absolutely MUST share mutable data between threads :(

> is there some kind of performance impact,

Not so anyone would notice.  A not-ready thread is, effectively, an extra pointer entry in some container in the kernel, (eg. a queue belonging to a semaphore).  Not worth bothering about.

Answer (score 0):

You need synchronized blocks, Atomics, and volatiles whenever two or more threads access mutable data.  Keep this to a minimum and it needn't affect your design.  There are lots of Java API classes that can handle this for you, such as BlockingQueue.

However, you *could* get into trouble if the nature of your problem/solution is perverse enough.  If your threads try to read/modify the same data at the same time, you'll find that most of your threads are waiting for locks and most of your cores are doing nothing.  To improve response time you'll have to let a lot more threads run, perhaps forgetting about the queue and letting them all go.

It becomes a trade off.  More threads chew up a lot of CPU time, which is okay if you've got it, and speed response time.  Fewer threads use less CPU time for a given amount of work (but what will you do with the savings?) and slow your response time.

**Key point:**  In this case you need a *lot* more running threads than you have cores to keep all your cores busy.

This sort of programming (multithreaded as opposed to parallel) is difficult and (irreproducible) bug prone, so you want to avoid it if you can before you even start to think about performance.  Plus, it only helps noticably if you've got more than 2 free cores.  And it's only needed for certain sorts of problems.  But you did ask for downsides, and it might pay to know this is out there.